# Combining and Merging Similar Part Numbers with filename

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to combine all the same part numbers on excel, in order to have one part number, but reference the filenames. However, when there is more than one file, I need to separate them by a comma.

Most of the vlookup and merging I have tried only pulls one item. And when I merge the part numbers I lose some filenames.Attached is the file showing the punctuated part number and file name. Some punctuated part numbers show up more than once while others only show up once. For every duplicate part number the filename is different as it contains a different view of the product.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be in one cell with commas in between? With a few clicks you can create a pivot table with part number and file name in the rows area. This will group the data by the part number.

You can use a formula if you have a list of unique part numbers. The formula in H2 uses TextJoin like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(Table1[part]=G2,Table1[file],""))
```

Copy down.

This is an array formula and unless you have an Excel version with the new Dynamic Array formulas, you need to confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

[image]

Comment: I have a part that doesn't exist on the pivot table and it will get stuck and print false for all file names thereafter. Once one part number didn't exist, it printed false on every single item for it's filename after that. Any suggestions on how to fix that? Basically, the part number exists on the primary sheet but not on the pivotal table on the other sheet because it has no file associated. My logical test references the primary table part number and pivotal table part number.

Comment: I don't understand. The pivot table (in the middle of my screenshot) is based on the data table (on the left in my screenshot). Any part number in the data table will show in the pivot table. What is YOUR pivot table based on? Maybe you need to point it to the real data.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify a little better. I have three separate sheets. I'm now trying to use a simple if statement on my primary sheet that reference back to the textjoin table. Essentially this if statement is checking the if the part numbers match then carry over the file names. I have a case where the part number exists on the primary sheet but does not exist in the textjoin table once one case is found like this everything after that will come out to be false.
=IF([@punctuatedPartNumber]=Table7[@PunctuatedPartNumber],Table7[@[Combined Files]])

Comment: Why do you use an IF statement to return the combined files? That ties you to the exact row and the other table may not have the data in that exact row. You could use a Vlookup instead and wrap an IfError around it.